# How to convert a pandas time series with hour (h) as index unit into pandas datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I am working on time-series data, where my pandas dataframe has indices specified in hours, like this:

```
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, ...]
```

This goes on for a few thousand hours. I know that the first measurement was taken on, let's say, `May 1, 2017 12:00`. How do I use this information to turn my indices into pandas datetime format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add hours to index by parameter `origin` in  [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
idx = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(13)}, index=idx)

start = 'May 1, 2017 12:00'
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, origin=start, unit='h')
print (df)
                      a
2017-05-01 12:00:00   0
2017-05-01 12:12:00   1
2017-05-01 12:24:00   2
2017-05-01 12:36:00   3
2017-05-01 12:48:00   4
2017-05-01 13:00:00   5
2017-05-01 13:12:00   6
2017-05-01 13:24:00   7
2017-05-01 13:36:00   8
2017-05-01 13:48:00   9
2017-05-01 14:00:00  10
2017-05-01 14:12:00  11
2017-05-01 14:24:00  12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.date_range` to specify the amount of periods based on the length of your `index` (in this case list) and specify the frequency, which is in this case `12min` or `1/5 H`:

```
l = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4]

data = {'Num':np.random.randint(1, 10, size=len(l))}

idx = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(2017, 5, 1, 12), periods=len(l), freq='12T')

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index= idx)
```

---

```
print(df)
                     Num
2017-05-01 12:00:00    8
2017-05-01 12:12:00    3
2017-05-01 12:24:00    3
2017-05-01 12:36:00    4
2017-05-01 12:48:00    8
2017-05-01 13:00:00    3
2017-05-01 13:12:00    6
2017-05-01 13:24:00    3
2017-05-01 13:36:00    4
2017-05-01 13:48:00    9
2017-05-01 14:00:00    5
2017-05-01 14:12:00    2
2017-05-01 14:24:00    6
```

Comment: Though I like your answer, I've accepted jezrael's answer since it can use any sequence of hour measurements, not just periodically placed ones. Your answer could, however, come in handy when one needs this perfect periodicity, and when rounding errors might have occured in the original sequence.